# Get nested object after self joining table

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

I'm trying to recreate twitter and I have problems with retweets. I want to store retweets in the same table as normal tweets. After joining users table with followers table and with tweets table to get tweets only from people who user follows for (in this case) user with id 1 (I use knex and put knex code here because I think it's more readable and easier to understand)

```
knex.select('users.email', 'tweets.id', 'tweets.body', 'tweets.type', 'tweets.original_tweet_id')
.from('users')
.join('followers', 'users.id', '=', 'followers.user_id')
.join('tweets', 'followers.following_id', '=', 'tweets.user_id')
.where('users.id', 1)
```

As a result I get this, so the second tweet is a retweet of the first one here.

```
{
    "email": "example@gmail.com",
    "id": 1,
    "body": 'My tweet',
    "type": "tweet",
    "original_tweet_id": null
},    
{
    "email": "example2@gmail.com",
    "id": 2,
    "body": null,
    "type": "retweet",
    "original_tweet_id": 1
},
```

So finally, my problem is that I want to also get nested original tweet for a retweet, something like this:

```
{
    "email": "example2@gmail.com",
    "id": 2,
    "body": null,
    "type": "retweet",
    "original_tweet": {
       "id": 1,
       "body": "My tweet",
       "email": "example@gmail.com"
    },

},
```

Is there anyway I can make it work? Is it even possible with raw sql or do I need some ORM for this?

Comment: It is kind of possible to do with raw SQL and json aggregating, but with `objection.js` it will be a lot easier. There is also loads of other thinkg in objection, which makes app development easier and it doesn't limit at all what kind of queries can be made to DB. https://www.jakso.me/blog/objection-to-orm-hatred

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks.